# GridLayout with SquareRelativeLayout item

Tags: android, grid-layout, square

I succeed to create a SquareRelativeLayout. Then I use this CustomLayout as one grid item of a GridLayout. I have 5 items for now (but it can be variable). For the first row, everything is fine. My item has a size of 400*400 but for the second row I have something like 400*429. I think my issue come from above, indeed I use a LinearLayout and my GridLayout has a height of layout:weight 0.50. Here is my current layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#66000000">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" ... />

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/droparea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            grid:columnCount="3"
            grid:orientation="horizontal">

            <SquareRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:background="@drawable/round_layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
                ...
            </SquareRelativeLayout>

            <SquareRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:background="@drawable/round_layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
                ...
            </SquareRelativeLayout>

            <SquareRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:background="@drawable/round_layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"> 
                ...
            </SquareRelativeLayout>

            <SquareRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:background="@drawable/round_layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
                ....
            </SquareRelativeLayout>

            <SquareRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:background="@drawable/round_layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
                ...
            </SquareRelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/draggable_linearlayout"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code of my SquareRelativeLayout :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

So I want to be able to set a variable height for my GridLayout but to keep squared items. Is it possible to let GridLayout fill the 29dp ? Did I miss an attribute ? If you can help me, don't hesitate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple, but yesterday I didn't think about it. You just need to use a ParentLayout for the GridLayout and then set to the layout_height of the GridLayout the attribute wrap_content and that's it :)